# Machine learning models with probability distribution output

Tags: machine-learning, inference, prediction

Given a feature vector $x$ I want to predict a continuous value $y$. However, I don't want to predict a single value for $y$, but rather the distribution of $y$'s given a particular set of feature values. What is the best way of doing this?

Assume I have a labeled training set of $x,y$ pairs to work from.